# Since Emacs 28: A new font problem with Arabic

Tags: fonts, bidirectional-support, fontsets

Since Emacs 28 I have a new problem with Arabic fonts.

1. I can't change the Arabic characters to the font of DejaVu Sans Mono (or others). This wasn't a problem before.
2. The old one: As you can see the glyphs aren't correct, the '-' after س is not correctly placed. It's *in* the place of the glyph of س.
   Sometimes I have the opposite problem: gaps between the characters. It depends usually of 'text-scale-adjust', if I change the scale the problem can disappear.

(Of course I started Emacs with the '-Q' option.)

Any suggestions? Is there a problem with 'HarfBuzz'?

EDIT: To see the difference: a screenshot in Word/LibreOffice Writer:

- The font is correct (also for the Arabic characters)
- The '-' is at the correct place
  [image: in Word/LibreOffice Writer]
  [image: Font problem with Arabic]